# How can I make Visual Studio Code use global eslint and not project eslint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

My project has eslint and it's own eslint.json file with its rules, I want to either use that my global eslint or override the project level one and just use my global eslint settings, is there a way to do that.

I currently have the following settings in my  VSC

```
"eslint.enable": true,
  "eslint.run": "onSave",
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "eslint.trace.server": "messages",
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "eslint.options": { "configFile": "/Users/almog/.eslintrc.json" },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initiate eslint in your required folder by using eslint cli command `elsint --init` and follow the instructions and then specify the eslintrc (eg: .eslintrc.js) 
setup file path in vscode `"eslint.options": { "configFile": "C:\\Users\\user66\\.eslintrc.js" }`